# How to fix "You must upgrade the project to target Microsoft Azure Tools 2.8"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, project, upgrade

I've got a project that's set to Azure 2.6. I have Visual Studio 2015 installed. I get prompted to upgrade the project (see image 1 below), which I do *not* want to do (it's production code and I don't know what the side effects may be, how many things might break).

I tried installing Azure 2.6 and related tools, but it doesn't help. Image 2 shows all the Azure related stuff I have installed

I have a coworker who has Visual Studio 2015 and can load the Azure project in the solution without a problem (see image 3). So it's clear that you don't *have* to upgrade the project.

I'm going to try installing VS 2013 Community Edition + Azure 2.7 tools to see if that satisfies it. I'm grasping at straws at this point.

Any ideas?

[image: Warning window asking to upgrade the project]

[image: Azure stuff I have installed already]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coworker helped me to come up with the solution:

1. Go to the "Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET - 2.6" page here:
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46892
2. Download "MicrosoftAzureTools.VS140.exe" and install it
3. Run appwiz.cpl from the run prompt and filter on "azure" in upper right
4. You should see "Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.6"
5. Open Visual Studio 2015 again and your project should now load without prompting to upgrade. Do a Rebuild All just in case to make sure it builds.

It turns out I had dang near everything installed except that one 2015 tools + 2.6 Azure combination.